# How to insert a delay in Jmeter based on Threads

Tags: jmeter, delay

I have 3 ThreadGroups namely: ThreadGroup1, ThreadGroup2 and ThreadGroup3. I want to run ThreadGroup 1 and 2 simultaneously and then once both these are done, I want to run ThreadGroup 3.

Is there a way I can put a timer/delay till a certain number threads are completed?

Comment: Setup `ThreadGroup3` as a `tearDown Thread Group`

Answer (score 1):

Configure the script as follows:

```
Test Plan

    --Thread Group01
    --Thread Group02
    --tearDown Thread Group03
```

As per JMeter documentation of [Tear Down Thread group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group),

> A special type of ThreadGroup that can be utilized to perform
>   Post-Test Actions. The behavior of these threads is exactly like a
>   normal Thread Group element. The difference is that these type of
>   threads execute after the test has finished executing its regular
>   Thread Groups.
>
> Note that by default it won't run if Test is gracefully shutdown, if
>   you want to make it run in this case, ensure you check the option "Run
>   tearDown Thread Groups after the shutdown of main threads" on Test
>   Plan element. If Test Plan is stopped, tearDown will not run even if
>   the option is checked.

**Configuration in the `Test Plan`**

Uncheck the option  <kbd>Run Thread Groups consecutively(i.e. run groups one at at a time)</kbd>

Check the option <kbd>Run tearDown Thread Groups after shutdown of main threads</kbd>

**Sample test script :**

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to provide - "Run Thread Groups consecutively" argument from jmeter command line ?